# Terminated Android apps not receiving pushes: Parse platform, Xamarin, and FCM

Tags: xamarin.forms, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a cross-platform app in Xamarin.Forms, with Parse as supplied by Sashi.do as a back end.

Here's what's working:

- sending & receiving push notifications on iOS
- sending & receiving push notifications between iOS and Android (with the exception explained below)
- receiving push notifications in Android when the app is in the foreground or background

Here's what's only working about 40% of the time:

- receiving push notifications in Android when the app is terminated

Now originally, when I couldn't get Android working on the receiving end, I ended up doing setting up a different service to receive Android pushes, specifically the CrossGeeks FirebasePushNotification Plugin  (https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)

I know it's a kludge and a bit of a Frankenstein's monster solution, but for the most part it works. Parse sends the notifications to Android devices, and the FirebasePushNotification Plugin catches them and shows them like Gob intended....

*...except when the Android app has been terminated.* Then it only works like 40% of the time.

So here are the details on my weird setup:

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.concierxge.Android" android:versionName="4.1.4" android:versionCode="27">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="CONCIERxGE">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
        <receiver android:name="parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <category android:name="com.concierxge.Android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.concierxge.Android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.concierxge.Android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

My Firebase-initializing code, found in my Android MainLauncher activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                ////Change for your default notification channel id here

                FirebasePushNotificationManager
                    .DefaultNotificationChannelId =
                    "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.
                    DefaultNotificationChannelName = "SecondChannel";
            }
            // Enable Firebase verbose logging
            firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);
            firebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("Todos");

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.IconResource =
                Resource.Drawable.ic_notification;

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.LargeIconResource =
                Resource.Drawable.ic_notification;

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance
                = NotificationImportance.Max;

            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                //custom token-logging code
            };
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current
                .OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
                {
                    foreach (var data in p.Data)
                    {
                        //output data to console
                    }
                };

            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived +=
                (sender, payload) =>
                {
                   //code that logs having received and handled notification
                   //...
                };
```

...and FWIW, yes, I *do* have Parse's own push-receiving event handler set up, like this:

```
ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += (obj, args) =>
            {
                   //code that logs having received and handled notification
                   //...
            };
```

...so I know this is weird guys, and not really how things are supposed to work, and if anyone had been able to help me get it all working in pure Parse I would be doing that, but no one could. I would *love* to eliminate the CrossGeeks part of the solution, but as of today I see no way to do that. So I have to figure out why CrossGeeks' FirebasePushNotification Plugin is working perfectly *except in this one case*.

Is it possible any kind soul just happens to have the specific oddball knowledge set to point me the way to freedom here?